# Why does umount automatically remove the mount point of a drive that has been mounted with a file manager?

Tags: umount

If I mount a drive using the file manager (I'm using PCManFM), the mount point is automatically removed when I run the `umount` command. However, if I mount by running `mkdir` and then `mount`, I have to manually remove the mount point after I have run `umount`.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to mount the drive using the `mount` command that will make the mount point be automatically removed?

**Update:** Is it similar to the reason for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405/why-do-i-need-root-privileges-to-umount-a-drive-at-the-command-line-but-not-in)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not up to `umount` to delete a directory so from command line you need to do it yourself.

You can use a script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount_point=/media/directory
umount $mount_point && rmdir $mount_point &
```

and save it as `umount.sh`.

The mount_point might be better off as a variable so you could so

```
./umount.sh /media/dir
```

Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
mount_point=$1
umount $mount_point && rmdir $mount_point &
```

> So why is it automatically removed when I run umount on a drive that has been mounted with a GUI file manager?

The answer to this is more likely a design decision. I have not found any documentation on this (maybe someone else can provide a link ;) )

Comment: So why is it automatically removed when I run umount on a drive that has been mounted with a GUI file manager?

Comment: still looking for that but it might be a design decision :P

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.10.

The problem of Rinzwind's script it that if it is interrupted then the directory will not be removed and this may cause problems later.

The mount point will be automatically removed if mounted by:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1
```

I think this is what the Ubuntu Disks graphical user interface does.  I don't know how and when the mount point is removed or not removed.

Looking at mount point created by `udisksctl` or Disks:

```
% stat /media/alba/EFI
  File: /media/alba/EFI
  Size: 512         Blocks: 1          IO Block: 512    directory
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 1           Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    alba)   Gid: ( 1000/    alba)
Access: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
Modify: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
Change: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

It has three links but `sudo find / -samefile /media/alba/EFI` only returns itself.