# How can I prevent orphan folders from being kept under /media/user?

Tags: mount, mountpoint

I noticed orphan folders from previously inserted external USB drives under `/media/user`.

How can I prevent the system from keeping these orphan folders?

*Folders in `media/user`:*

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279270/why-does-umount-automatically-remove-the-mount-point-of-a-drive-that-has-been-mo

Comment: Dear @Ron, thank you very much for sharing the link! If I understand correctly, then this is the normal behaviour of `umount` to not delete the unmounted folders?

Comment: Yes. They won't cause any harm and they will be recreated when you attach the drives anyway.

Comment: see this: "Partition mount point keeps changing" https://askubuntu.com/questions/974741/partition-mount-point-keeps-changing