# Using `umount` for USB mounted ext4 volume without `sudo`

Tags: 14.04, permissions, fstab, umount

I mount a USB HDD used for intermittent plugin backup via the fstab entry:

```
# <file system>                           <mount point> <type>  <options>                                                                        <dump> <pass>
UUID=cd9f3fc4-f67f-42c4-8190-21d2766d2b65 /mnt/Bu-ehd2  ext4    rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,noauto,nofail,relatime,user_xattr,acl,comment=x-gvfs-show 0      2
```

To unmount, `sudo umount /mnt/Bu-ehd2` works, but trying to unmount as a regular (non-root) user:

```
$ umount /mnt/Bu-ehd2
umount: only root can unmount UUID=cd9f3fc4-f67f-42c4-8190-21d2766d2b65 from /mnt/Bu-ehd2
```

Why it is so is covered by @MariusGedminas' [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405/why-do-i-need-root-privileges-to-umount-a-drive-at-the-command-line-but-not-in) on AU, but not how to circumvent the usage restriction on `umount`without `sudo`.

- Adding `user` to the mount options does not help.
- Adding `users` does help but unmounting by any user becomes possible even after mounting was done based on an `/etc/fstab` entry. A possible but poor solution.
- Adding `uid=1000,owner` breaks the mount process altogether with:

> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdc1:
>
> Command-line `mount "/mnt/Bu-ehd2"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
>   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,...

I checked:

```
$ df -l | grep Bu-ehd2
/dev/sdc1        192162396     60744 182317284       1% /mnt/Bu-ehd2

$ ls -lAsF /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdc1
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 29 11:24 cd9f3fc4-f67f-42c4-8190-21d2766d2b65
-> ../../sdc1

$ stat /mnt/Bu-ehd2 | head -4
File: ‘/mnt/Bu-ehd2’
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 821h/2081d  Inode: 2           Links: 3
Access: (0770/drwxrwx---)  Uid: ( 1000/someuser)   Gid: (    0/    root)

$ stat /dev/sdc1 | head -4
File: ‘/dev/sdc1’
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 176539      Links: 1     Device type: 8,21
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)

$ blkid | grep Bu-ehd2 # yields nothing on /dev/sdc1 when actually 
$                      #+ mounted on `/mnt/Bu-ehd2`
```

**Q:** Is unmouting as a regular user impossible due to the fact that the mounted device is owned by root ? If so, how do I make the device umountable by `someuser` just by issuing cmd `umount /dev/sdc1` ? Ideally that would be by making `someuser` the owner of its own external usb HDD device.

*Note:* I prefer not to resort to `sudo visudo` in order to write a sudo-exception rule for every different user, for `umount`. It would still force every `someuser` to type `sudo umount /mnt/Bu-ehd2` instead of just `umount /dev/sdc1` anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need root privileges to umount a drive at the command line, but not in nautilus? How to change?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/405/why-do-i-need-root-privileges-to-umount-a-drive-at-the-command-line-but-not-in)

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/552503/stop-asking-for-authentication-to-mount-usb-stick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `root`, a user can not `umount` any filesystem mounted by some other user.

If you have used the `user` option in `mount` (`/etc/fstab`), you can check the output of `mount` command, you will see the `user=` showing the user who has mounted the filesystem. Only that user (and `root`) can use `umount` to unmount the filesystem.

There are hacky ways to do unmounting as a different user but i don't think there is any direct `umount` way.

---

Here is a function (based on OP's idea) that will run `umount` or `gvfs-mount` based on EUID. This could be put in `/etc/bash.bashrc` so that it will be available on all user's interactive shells:

```
unmount () {
    if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]]; then
        { [[ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 || "$1" =~ ^-.* ]] && "$(command -v umount)" "$1" || gvfs-mount -u "$1" ;}
    else
        printf "Usage: unmount [option -h [|-V]|mount-point|device-path]\n"
    fi
}
```

Comment: ok. I get it.  @MarcelStimberg provides an old but valid workaround from cli in https://askubuntu.com/questions/405/why-do-i-need-root-privileges-to-umount-a-drive-at-the-command-line-but-not-in , in the form of `gvfs-mount -u /media/the_device`. But just introducing `user` in the mount options doesn't help (see OP) and introducing `uid=1000` (for instance) breaks the fstab entry (see OP), at least for an ext4 FS...

Comment: @Cbhihe If you use `user`, then the user mounted it can unmount it..not any random user..also i have said there is no direct `umount` way..

Comment: ...a slight misunderstanding perhaps. I am indeed talking about a user unmounting the USB ext4 fs it previously mounted based on the fstab entry.  Or is it that when there is an fstab entry, the usb FS is actually mounted by root from within the non-root user session ? In any case placing `user` in the options and letting fstab do its job does not allow me to unmount as non-root. I have the feeling that mounting according to an fstab entry is tantamount to root mounting the FS. True or False ?

Comment: True..mount does not depend on session, it depends on user..if root has mounted something , only root can umount it..also if a non-root user has mounted something, no other non-root user except it can umount it (root can obviously)....also i am talking about `mount` - `umount` here, not any other tools as tools like `udisks` manipulate the device directly and offer services via DBus..

Comment: +1. Got it despite being thick today. Finally I just went ahead and included users in the `/etc/fstab` entry mount options. It's a poor cop-out, a bit like leaving yr house door wide open so you can be sure to always be able to get in if you forget yr key... So can anyone else. Another better way would be to (just for `someuser`) "overload" (borrowed terminology!) the umount cmd  with a small function placed in `~/.profile` and in `~/.bash_profile` (or in `~/.bash_login`), which would catch the error message and redirect $1 to be handled by `gvfs-mount -u $1`. Just an idea.

Comment: @Cbhihe Lol..good analogy..yes, that idea is very simple and straight forward..

Comment: Working on that "overloaded" `umount ()` idea now. Will post shortly in a comment so that, if you like it enough, you can include it in yr answer before I mark it as accepted.

Comment: Here (https://paste.ubuntu.com/15593311/) is my little overloaded `umount()` function to be placed in .bashrc or in ~/.profile and in ~/.bash_profile (or in ~/.bash_login).  Feel free to modify it if necessary and to add it to yr answer, as a workaround to the limitation of `/bin/umount`. I will then mark yr answer as complete.

Comment: @Cbhihe modified..check my edits..

Comment: ok,  although you don't test for a lone option syntax such as: `umount -h` or `umount -V`, which were correctly handled in my pastebin suggestion. Also I believe you can actually call yr function `umount` instead of `unmount`.  I think that in that case, using the syntax `command umount ...` inside the function block prevents a spurious recursive call from happening. It behaves well in my test on two 14.04.4 boxes.

Comment: @Cbhihe duh..i forgot about those, add the checking at your will please..yes, `command` will explicitly search for external binaries and you can call it `umount` but i prefer to remain cleaner :)

Comment: Done and tested. I got rid of "command -v" in `"$(command -v gvfs-mount)" "$1"` because upon adding the missing option `-u` to implement `gvfs-mount` unmout capability, the construct `"$(command -v gvfs-mount -u)" "$1"` broke.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `udisksctl` to unmount without root privileges:

```
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: yes Serg, thanks. But it is already well covered by `gvfs-mount -u /dev/sdc1` in comments to heemayl's  answer above. I see the two approaches as equivalent even as `udisksctl` is "finer grained" than the simpler `gvfs-mount` ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `udisksctl mount/unmount -b /dev/sdX`. To use mount or umount without root privileges you need to edit `/etc/sudoers` file with **visudo** and add the lines:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount, /bin/umount
```

Then reboot.